# Exception occuring while extracting the value of the node in xdocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an xml like :

```
<RunResult>
  <PreviewRecords></PreviewRecords>
  <RecordsProcessed>100</RecordsProcessed>
  <LogError>false</LogError>
</RunResult>
```

I am using the following command to fetch the value of the node `RecordsProcessed`  ,

```
int NofRecords = 0;
NofRecords = Convert.ToInt32(xdRunResultDoc.Root.Element("RunResult").Element("RecordsProcessed").Value;
```

But at this line it is throwing exception " **object reference not set to an instance of an object**".

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: check the value of xdRunResultDoc.Root.Element("RunResult") by debug the code, i think u can solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xdRunResultDoc.Root` already points to `<RunRdesult>` element, so you don't have to call `Element("RunResult")` again.

And I suggest using `(int)` casting on `XElement` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`: [`XElement Explicit Conversion (XElement to Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348319.aspx)

```
int NofRecords = (int)xdRunResultDoc.Root.Element("RecordsProcessed");
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int NofRcord = Convert.ToInt32(xdRunResultDoc.Root.Element("RecordsProcessed").Value);
```

See this link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
string xmlstring = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <RunResult>
        <PreviewRecords></PreviewRecords>
        <RecordsProcessed>100</RecordsProcessed>
        <LogError>false</LogError>
    </RunResult>";

System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

int NofRecords = 0;

NofRecords = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Element("RunResult").Element("RecordsProcessed").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Find the solution by your self, Why don't you debug and see which causing *"object reference not set to an instance of an object"* error?

You can add watch to `xdRunResultDoc` and in the run time you can check what is root node and what you get for `xdRunResultDoc.Root.Element("RunResult")` etc..

Here your root node is `RunResult` you can't find Elements inside root node called `RunResult`

[You better check this code project tutorial.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

read entire text from the xml file and load that to a XmlDocument

```
XmlNode rootNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("RunResult");
                            if (rootNode.HasChildNodes)
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode node in rootNode.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    if (node.Name =="RecordsProcessed")
                                    {

                                        NofRecords=Convert.ToInt32(node.InnerText);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```